# Docker-compose restart policy cause logs to be cut

Tags: docker, jboss, docker-compose

I run two containers inside docker compose yaml file. One is application server (with deployed application) and second one is oracle database. I have following yaml file.

```
services:
  jboss-7.0.3:
    image: jboss-7.0.3
    build:  ../dockerfiles/jboss-eap-7.0.3
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '9990:9990'
      - '9999:9999'
      - '8787:8787'
    restart: always

  oracle11:
    image: oracle11
    build: ../dockerfiles/oracle-11xe-dima
    ports:
      - "48088:48088"
      - "1521:1521"
      - "40022:40022"
    restart: always
```

I wanted to debug why server can't connect to database (in standalone-full.xml file i have oracle11 name as host specified). Now what is strange for me I can't se error which exatcly cause jboss to restart. It's always around db connection but i should be able to see some error in logs, but before error log appears jboss restarts. Thus I can't see what caused the error. Even without restart policy it gets kill signal and log immediately stops. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: 1. You should define a `container_name` for your services - otherwise they will get a pre- and postfix. And you should use the container name of your oracle in your jboss config. 2. *without* restart policy, you should be able to see the logs even if the container immediately stops. What is your command to run this compose file??

Comment: 1. As you said container names have post and prefixes, but when I log to container bash i can ping oracle11 sucessfully, so it seems that this hostname is resolvable. 2. Without restart policy i have the same issue, i see only `2017-10-19 08:32:18,744 INFO  [stdout] (LifecycleManager-0) Init PCEJdbcMonitorService` This is the last line which i see (next app is going to connect to db, and normally there are errors, warns etc. My command is docker-compose up -d

Comment: maybe you could try to use `depends_on: -  oracle11` inside your jboss

Comment: yes, but right now it seems that oracle11 works fine. I can connect to this container from host machine, so I'm sure that oracle11 works fine. I will try to define container names to be sure about this

Comment: I just thought about oracle didn't finished starting when jboss tried to access it. Maybe you need something like *sleep 30* at your command in jboss.

Comment: when jboss stopped (without restart) i run container manually when oracle was available with the same effect. it means that it's not the case. container_name neither help. But still my original question is, why logs are cut - because of that i'm not able to see what was the real reason of jboss failure

Comment: @Munchkin thanks for your help, look at my answer, i finally found what was the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on.. It was really simple mistake - reason why my logs were cut was that.. actually there were not cut. I had to small memory in my docker host machine and JBoss were killed by system, so this was the reason. Now, after increasing memory to docker host machine, everything works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

From your `yaml` file, i could see that you have not linked your server to database. Use `links:oracle11` field in your service `jboss-7.0.3`. And the `DB URI` should contain your db container address/db service name.

Comment: thanks, but now it's not needed to use links, docker-compose build network and both container can use their names as hostnames to communicate within this network.